# My server is returning an Internal Server Error during a long PHP request

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a situation when running a long PHP request on my server. I configured my `php.ini` setting values as `post_max_size` to 32M and `memory_limit` to 512MB

The server returns this error however:

[image]

So, I checked my Apache log and I'm only seeing this:

```
[Wed Oct 23 04:19:31.076537 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31374] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 23 04:19:31.076556 2019] [core:notice] [pid 31374] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 23 04:20:27.780880 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 31378] mod_fcgid: process 31412 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Oct 23 04:21:42.023245 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31374] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 23 04:21:42.096780 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 32144] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Oct 23 04:21:42.118983 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32159] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 23 04:21:42.119006 2019] [core:notice] [pid 32159] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 23 04:23:03.477187 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 32162] mod_fcgid: process 32179 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Oct 23 04:23:34.223806 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32159] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 23 04:23:34.369164 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 32257] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Oct 23 04:23:34.393331 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32270] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 23 04:23:34.393349 2019] [core:notice] [pid 32270] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 23 04:24:25.196653 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 32274] mod_fcgid: process 32292 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Oct 23 04:27:18.281931 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 32274] mod_fcgid: process 490 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Oct 23 04:31:25.756624 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 32270] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 23 04:31:25.896784 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 1429] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Oct 23 04:31:25.918894 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1448] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 23 04:31:25.918914 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1448] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Oct 23 04:32:38.260141 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1452] mod_fcgid: process 1474 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed Oct 23 04:38:42.999506 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1452] mod_fcgid: process 26667 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

I have the same site running on another server with the same configuration and it's running well, but in this test server I'm receiving the above error.

What else can I do to get more info about this error (because the Apache log is not returning me enough information about it).

Here's some additional details:

I'm running a single PHP script connecting to a MySQL database (around one thousand of entries - this is going well running it trough Workbench directly, for example) with CodeIgniter framework, but this is not part of the problem because the only thing I need to know is how to force my server to return more information about the Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

Apache log does not help fixing problem, in this way.
You need to check **PHP log**, i.e enabling via PHP itself.